# How to pass a unit of work / entity context across Action filters and Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller, action-filter

I am trying to make sure that my MVC application only uses one DbContext per Request in order to reduce number of times a Db connection is open and so there are no concurrency issues.

This means i will need to use the same context in my Global Action Filters as well as my Controllers.

I have tried something like this

```
public class LayoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        MembershipUser loggedInUser = Membership.GetUser();

        MyUnitOfWork uow = new MyUnitOfWork();
        ViewBag.FullName = uow.UserService.GetUser().FullName

        filterContext.ActionParameters["unitOfWork"] = uow;
    }
}
```

However the context is disposed when i try to read it from the controller as shown below

```
  public ActionResult Logout(MyUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        ViewBag.Something = uow.ExampleService.GetMyObject();

        return RedirectToAction("LogIn");
    }
```

I get the same issue with the context being disposed when i try to share the same unitOfWork object by casting a property of a base controller class

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public RequestboxUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
}

 public class LayoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        MembershipUser loggedInUser = Membership.GetUser();

        BaseController baseController = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;
        ViewBag.FullName = baseController.unitOfWork.UserService.GetUser().FullName

        filterContext.ActionParameters["unitOfWork"] = uow;
    }
}
```

The context is disposed when i try to access it in the controller and i have read in a few places that you should not use base controller class so i am unsure of what i can do.

What are the recommended ways to share a entity context between ActionFilters and Controllers

Comment: Use an IoC framework like Autoac to inject your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the DBContext as part of the Controller setup, and have it available via an internal property on the controller.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private MyUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    internal MyUnitOfWork UnitOfWork 
    { 
        get { return unitOfWork; } 
    }
}
```

You will then be able to access the context in the filter attribute like this:

```
MyController controller = (MyController)filterContext.Controller
MyUnitOfWork uow = controller.UnitOfWork;
```

There's no need to pass the unit of work back to the action method in the controller, because the controller already has the object, and it can be accessed via the same internal property.